# How to check out a maven project with egit AND a custom archetype

Tags: java, eclipse, git, egit, maven-archetype

I created a maven archetype which gives me a special folder structure and pom.xml which I often use for my projects in eclipse. Now I created a concrete maven project from the archetype and started working in it. The project is under source control in an external git repository.

How can I check out the project from git (best by using egit) into eclipse AND have my archetype applied to it again?

Currently when I check out the project, I get only the folders which haven't been empty. Any folder that doesn't belong to the standard archetype is not recognized as source folder...

----- EDIT -----

To clarify the question:
I have two options to start with.

Option 1) I could create a new eclipse project from git. The question then is, how do I add the missing pieces from the archetype? Addon question: After creating the project I worked on it and so some changes to the generated files have been made (e.g. example files have been replaced). How do I add the missing pieces from the archetype without overwriting my changes?

Option 2) I could create a new eclipse project from the archetype. A problem is then that I have to enter information that is stored in the pom.xml in git. So lets assume that we know the correct information (artifactId, etc.). How do I connect the newly created project to the git repository and apply the changes from git to the repository? In this order, there should be no overwrite problems.

Comment: I believe you have some issues with Git here, it doesn't cares about empty directories. Try adding an empty `.placeholder` file to these folders and let's see if that helps after a new 'check out' into Eclipse (it is a clone under the hood).

Comment: thats not the only problem. some other folders are generated, but eclipse doesn't see them as source folder. After some thinking I assume that the right order would be 1) create a new project following the archetype and 2) insert the content from git into the project. This way, the folders are created correctly. I still have to try it out...

Comment: Oh ok, it seems I got it wrong :-)